# Posting open gtaph story with object 'profile'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I want to post a story from my application about other user. I want to get a story with link to profile like this http://prntscr.com/def3b6.
I use OpenGraph Object: profile. I writed tags: profile:first_name, profile:username, profile:gender, profile:last_name, fb:profile_id.
I got this: http://prntscr.com/def3l4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://tsa.nevomedia.ru/fb/social_slots/media/wall/profileTest.html - Object link

Comment: _“with link to profile like this”_ – that is not an Open Graph Story, but simply one of the meta posts Facebook creates automatically. I don’t think you can get the same with your app’s own story. Plus, custom stories are deprecated anyway.